# solving $9x^2+9y^2+27x+12y+19=0$

Tags: circles

I'm a bit uncertain about how I solve this right; my calculations so far are

$9x^2+9y^2+27x+12y+19=0$

$(x^2+y^2+3x+(4/3)y+19/9=0$

$(x^2+(3/2)x+9/4) +(y^2+(2/3)y+4/9) =7/12$

I'm getting the right answer for circle of center points $(-3/2, -2/3),$ but I get ${\sqrt 7/12}$ instead of ${\sqrt 21/6}$; what am I missing?
Many thanks!

Comment: Your calculation is not clear.  How do you get $\frac 32x$ and $\frac 23y$  in the third equation?

Comment: You want to get $(x+ (3/2))^2 + (y+ (2/3))^2 = ?$

Comment: $\sqrt{7/12} = \sqrt{21/36} = ?$

Comment: Did you mean $(x^2+3x+9/4)+(y^2+(4/3)y+4/9),$ which is $(x+(3/2))^2+(y+(2/3))^2$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{7/12}=\dfrac{\sqrt{7/3}}2=\dfrac{\sqrt{21}}6$$

Comment: Thanks... Turns out im just an idiot-.-'